# How do I add a C library to a Microsoft Visual C++ project?

Tags: c, file

I am working on a project in Microsoft Visual C++. I want to add the `USB` device driver library which is a `C` library.

Do I need to build some extra library to add this `USB` library?

Comment: Have you compiled the USB library yourself or do you have the .lib files for Windows?

Comment: @jonsca i have .lib files for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project menu, then properties, configuration properties tab

- at C/C++, general, put the header file directory in "Additional Include Directories"
- in Linker, general, add the directory that the .lib files are in to "Additional Library Directories"
- in Linker, input, add the names of the .lib files to "Additional Dependencies"

Compile you program, and if necessary, copy any .dlls you will need to the directory containing the .exe